# How would I parse multiple variables through a dynamic link in html?

Tags: html, hyperlink

This may be a relatively simple answer, although I can't seem to find any solution online.

I've been parsing a variable through a dynamic link by using the following line: 
`a href="play.php?inputType=album"`

inputType being the variable I want to parse. Although I also want to parse another variable through the hyperlink although I'm not sure if or how I can add it to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple parameters can be passed through the URL by separating them with multiple "&". Here is an example of the same:

```
<a href="play.php?inputType=album&name=test">
```

Comment: The &amp; is only needed in XML or XHTML - a simple & is enough